# Insert CollectionView into TableView Cell in ios

Tags: objective-c

I have a tableview which have 4 row. then i want to insert a collectionview into tableview cell and each collectionview have different cell. But i can't do that. can any one help me out or any suggesition?

Comment: Each collectionview have different element.... like one cell have only imageview other collectionview cell have only label etc.... so, any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can give different CellIdentifiers for every TableViewCell and createa different rows in InterfaceBuilder or inside 
cellForRowAtIndexPath

Dont forget to provide `dataSource` and `delegate` for every collectionView that you will create for TableViewCell

Pseudocode:

YN Means YourNamespace

```
YNDataSourceDelegate1* data1;
YNDataSourceDelegate2* data2;
YNDataSourceDelegate3* data3;
YNDataSourceDelegate4* data4;

const NSInteger COLLECTION_VIEW_TAG = 1001;

NSArray* providers=@[data1,data2,data3,data4];
NSArray* rowIds=@[@"row1",@"row2",@"row3",@"row4"];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:rowIds[indexPath.row]];

UICollectionView * collectionView = (UICollectionView*)[cell viewWithTag:COLLECTION_VIEW_TAG];

collectionView.dataSource = providers[indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: but i want to create one tableview cell and one collectionview cell. and then i reused a tableview cell using (indexpath.row == somethig). but one more thing each collection view have different element. can i do that? and you understand my question?

Comment: Then just use single identifier for tableviewcell

Comment: Can you send me your technical requirements then ?

Comment: hi @ekiyanov, it's a long time... i want a layout design like android app store, where collectionview have every tableview cells and different data. can you understand, my requirement. I go throw many tutorial but every tutorial have swift language but i am not able to work swift language, can you help with objective c in that type of UI design?  And please also go throw   https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/

Answer (score 0):

**This code will help you**

**yourViewController.h**

```
    @interface testingvc : UIViewController
    <
    UITableViewDelegate,
    UITableViewDataSource,
    UICollectionViewDelegate,
    UICollectionViewDataSource
    >


    {
    IBOutlet UITableView *tbleeView;

    }
```

**yourViewController.m**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tbleeView.delegate=self;
    tbleeView.dataSource=self;
    tbleeView.pagingEnabled=YES;

    }
```

**yourTableViewCell.h**(UITableViewCell)

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UICollectionView *clview;
```

**yourViewController.m**

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    //#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    //#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return 10;

    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static  NSString *identifierDriver = @"abcdefgh";

    yourTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierDriver forIndexPath:indexPath];

//testing table cell is a UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[testingTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifierDriver];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor]; 

//@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UICollectionView *clview;-this method is implement in UITableViewCell

// call collection view delegate method in table view cell.

    cell.clview.delegate=self;
    cell.clview.dataSource=self;
    cell.clview.parentIndexpath = indexPath;
    cell.clview.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];
    cell.clview.pagingEnabled=YES;//optional



    return cell;
    }

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSArray *collectionViewArray =  [_arrayProducts [[(IndexedCollectionView *)collectionView parentIndexpath].row]objectForKey:@"inventory"];//arrProducts is an array where i get all the data from webservice

    return [collectionViewArray count];

    }
    - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point

    {
    return 0;
    }
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    yourColloectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"abcdef" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *Products  = [_arrayProducts[[(yourCollectionView *)collectionView parentIndexpath].row]objectForKey:@"inventory"];//arrProducts is an array where i get all the data from webservice


      NSLog(@"object ibde xis ----%ld",[Products count]);
     if (indexPath.row>[Products count]-1 )
     {
    NSLog(@"index not found");

     }

      else
    {

      NSDictionary *dictdata = [Products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSLog(@"dictdata is =====%@",dictdata);

   //do your code here


    }


    if (indexPath.row % 2)
    {
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];;
    }
    else
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];;

    return cell;
    }
    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
    {
    return 0;
    }


    - (void)collectionView:(IndexedCollectionView *)collectionView
     didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {



     NSInteger tableindex = collectionView.parentIndexpath.row;

    NSLog(@"collection path row is ----%ld",tableindex);
     NSLog(@"collection path row is ----%ld",indexPath.row);

    //you can get all that index path number . Enjoy :)

     }
```

Comment: you want to load collection view in all table view cell?

Comment: Yes.... But I want every tableview row show different color... like 1st Table view row Start Red color,2nd row start white color and so on.. it's possible?

Comment: I thik if your code will work then Every tableview cell show same  output.... but try to understand... i want different color of 2nd tableview cell,3rd tableview cell and so on... it's possible?

Comment: Yes you can change each and every cell background color.. with this code . I already used it in my code and it working perfectly. You can change the color of your table view cell background color. SECOND :- the easiest way to do that is hit the webservice and put that response in an array and reload your table view .

Comment: @ Dishant, try to understand. i insert one  collectionview into tableview cell,that is done. Just imagine  tableview have 4 cell/row... then i want to show different content each collection view (under tableview cell.... like android store).... please help me out with that thought. your code is working but output is not similar which i aspect.

Comment: @sanjibde ok ok now i understand. Sorry for that confusion.

Comment: @ Dishant, It's Ok. So You Understand....  I am waiting for your answare

Comment: @sanjibde I Updated my full code with webservice data too. Now you can get everything here.

Comment: I Can't sorry but i will send you that files.  .h and .m and those cells too