# Insert CollectionView into Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

Insert a collectionView into Tableview Cell. Like Android play store. Any One Help me [image]

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried and what issues you may have faced in the implementation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834772/insert-collectionview-into-tableview-cell-in-ios/42850698#42850698

Comment: Please Check this description image, which is uploded.... but i don't understand,how can i do that

Comment: Providing an image is not enough, you need to provide a sample of your attempted code, otherwise you may get all sorts of detailed answers that you may not be equipped to implement without further guidance. Or you may not get any answers because we do not feel that you put enough effort into the question and attempted solution to warrant us spending our free time to help you earn money

Comment: hello @Cris Schaller, i couldn't upload my code... when i upload my code into stack overflow...it could be error.... Thats why i upload an image.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a Tableviewcell is just another view with a frame and bounds and as a view, it can have subviews, CollectionViews are also views and can be added to any other view, so you just add a Collectionview as a SubView of the cell.

I suggest take a programmatically approach instead of IB, here is my repo with code that can help you achieve your task https://github.com/jamesrochabrun/AppStoreLayout

Comment: is this demo is not availabel  in objective c ???

Comment: I only build it on swift, but you can follow the same patterns, hope it can help.

Comment: I don't know swift language. so sir, please provide me objective-c demo. It's very helpfull for me.